# Nested generator functions in python

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

Consider a tuple `v = (a,b,c)` and a generator function `generate(x)` which receives an item from the tuple and generates several options for each item.

What is the pythonic way of generating a set of all the possible combinations of the result of `generate(x)` on each item in the tuple?

I could do this:

```
v = (a,b,c)
for d in generate(v[0]):
    for e in generate(v[1]):
        for f in generate(v[2]):
            print d,e,f
```

but that's just ugly, plus I need a generic solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 2.6 has the function [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) that does what you want:

```
import itertools
v = (a, b, c)
for d, e, f in itertools.product(*(generate(x) for x in v)):
  print d, e, f
```

From the docs:

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a
>   generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as
>   ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

Comment: Looks to be helpful, how would I iterate over the result?

Comment: @Yuval: `for i in product(*(generate(x) for x in v)): do_whatever_you_want(i)`

Comment: @Yuval: It returns a generator that lists all combinations. I've updated my answer to show how to iterate over the results.